# Iterating through, and using the contents of, files in a folder

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, cidr

Evening folks.

I'm trying to iterate through the contents of a folder, and use the contents of each file in the folder.

More specifically, i have a folder of JSON files that have CIDRs in them. I need to iterate through the files, read the file, compare the CIDRs to the IP that's searching through it, then move on to the next file, if the IP isn't found in the CIDR list within the file.

I've been able to load and iterate through a single file, parse the JSON file, and compare the CIDRs to the JSON using the "ipaddress" and "json" modules built into Python. But when i try to iterate through the individual files, i get a "file not found" error.

The real catch is that i'm trying to do this entirely with standard library Python modules, which is throwing me for a loop.

Here's what i've done so far.

This function can read the JSON file if one is loaded specifically:

```
import json

with open('example.json', 'r') as example_file:
    example_data = json.load(example_file)
    print(json.dumps(chime_data, indent=4))

print(type(example_data))
print(example_data.keys())
print(example_data['JsonKey'])

individual_item = chime_data['JsonKey']
print(JsonKey)
```

And this one will read and Compare the CIDRs to an input IP address

```
import json
from ipaddress import ip_network, ip_address

with open('Example.json', 'r') as example_file:
    example_data = json.load(example_file)

    example = example_data['JsonKey']
    
    print("Please provide valid IP: ")
    ip = input()

def in_example(ip, cidr):
    return ip_address(ip) in ip_network(cidr)

for data in cidr:
    if ip_address(ip) in ip_network(data):
        print("The IP is in the list as", data)
    else:
        continue
print("Have nice day.")
```

And these both work. But when i try to iterate through using this method, i get a "File not Found" error

```
import json
import os

working_directory = '/Desktop/ExampleFolder'


for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(working_directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.json'):
            with open(file, 'r') as example_file:
                example_data = json.load(example_file)
                print(json.dumps(example_data, indent=4))
        else:
            print('Well shit, something broke')

        print(type(example_data))
        print(example_data.keys())
        print(example_data['JsonKey'])

        cidrs = chime_data['JsonKey']
        print(cidrs)
```

Which prints out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/jsonread.py", line 19, in <module>
    with open(file, 'r') as example_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'first_file.json'
```

Would love some feedback and guidance.

Comment: One possibility is a race condition. If the file is deleted between the `os.walk` and the `with open`, it would cause this error.

Comment: Oh that's interesting. Is there a way for me to maintain it, or check to see if it's being deleted?

The file itself isn't deleted, as it's still sitting in the folder. But maybe, in python, i thinks it is, for some reason?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're using the filename without the directory. Try: `with open(os.path.join(subdir, files), 'r') as example_file: `.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rostade/Desktop/jsonread.py", line 19, in <module>
    with open(os.path.join(subdir, files), 'r') as chime_file:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/posixpath.py", line 90, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/genericpath.py", line 152, in _check_arg_types
    raise TypeError(f'{funcname}() argument must be str, bytes, or '
TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'list'

Comment: New error! It's progress of a sort. Going to read up more on the "join()" argument, to see what's going on her

Comment: Sorry, that should be "file" rather than "files": `with open(os.path.join(subdir, file), 'r') as example_file:`